# How to filter out .responseXML based on a tag value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

So I have an XML file which I am using javascript to parse through and convert to HTML using XMLHttpRequest.  What I want to do is filter out elements that contain the string English in the link tag and save into another array.  That way I can add a limit parameter and loop through the new array to control how many elements populate on the page.  I'm pretty new to coding and am not quite sure how I would take the responseXML filter it and put into another array or if that's even the best apprach.  The basic XML file structure and my code is below:

```
<channel>
<item>
      <title>Test Title</title>
      <link>https://www.test.com/English/rest-of-link</link>
      <description>This is a dummy despcription</description>
      <pubDate>Wed, 31 May 2017 17:52:51 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
<item>
      <title>Test Title2</title>
      <link>https://www.test.com/Spanish/rest-of-link</link>
      <description>This is another dummy despcription</description>
      <pubDate>Wed, 31 May 2017 17:52:51 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
</channel>



var myitems;
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        printHtml(this, limit);          
    }              
};
xhttp.open("GET", "rss.xml", true);
xhttp.send(); 


 function printHtml(xml) {


var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
myitems = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('item');

/*********/
filter out items with the string English in the url into another array
/*********/

i = 0;
for(i=0;i<myitems.length;++i) {
    var mylink = myitems[i].getElementsByTagName('link')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        var html = '<a href="'+ mylink +'"><div class="home-entry-header"></a></div>';

        $(".full-list").append(html); 

}

}
```

Comment: so you want only the link tags to be parsed for the word English or the entire document? and you want an array of [english, english english]?

Comment: I want to loop through the entire xml document and store each whole item that has "English" in the link tag in an array.  I'll be displaying the title, description, and pubDate tags on the page as well. I only included the link tag in my code to simplify it.  So I guess it would be storing objects in the new array, so that I can grab the title, description, link, and pubDate to form into html.

Comment: can you can provide the input you are getting from your request and the output you would like in the form of a structure like an array of objects etc..., I will have a better idea of the kind of filter you will need to solve your problem.

Comment: I'm not 100% how the request works but, this line "myitems = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('item');" which creates an array of objects that look like this [item, item, item, item, item].  Then this line "myitems[i].getElementsByTagName('link')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;" grabs the text from the link node. So I guess it would be search through the original array of objects [item, item, item, item,item] see which one's have "English" in the link node and putting it in a new array of the same structure.

Comment: I'm wondering would this work or is there a better way? `for(i=0;i<myitems.length;++i) {
        var mylink = myitems[i].getElementsByTagName('link')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        
        
        var newArray[];
        var isEnglish = mylink.includes("/English/");
        
        if(isEnglish){
            newArray.push(myitems[i]);
        }}`

Comment: you are getting your data from another location. which is what I am assuming because of XMLHttpRequest. Using selectors only makes sense if you are dealing with the dom object model. you can try the document response property

Comment: well when I type myitems[i] in the console in returns `<item>
      <title>Test Title</title>
      <link>https://www.test.com/English/rest-of-link</link>
      <description>This is a dummy despcription</description>
      <pubDate>Wed, 31 May 2017 17:52:51 GMT</pubDate>
</item>` so whatever magic the .responseXML method does seems to allow me to use selectors.

Comment: problem solved. I think it's because XMLHttpRequest() carries document property. Mdn didn't mention support so didn't want to recommend it.